# Chatbox not expanding <p> when it fix in max-width

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, chat

I'm trying to make a chat view, but I'm facing a CSS problem which is hard to explain for me in English so I will show a screenshot of it:

[image: screenshot]

I have a parent div which limits how much its child div's width can scale to. Inside the inner div, I have a paragraph tag which contains the text. Why doesn't the inner div scale to its maximum width and render the paragraph tag in only 1 line. For sure, I'm missing something really stupid. The code is here:

```css
.meMessages {
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.msg-details {}

.chat-message {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 9%;
    padding-right: 9%;


    .right-bubble {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        max-width: 100%;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        background: #dcf8c6;
        border-top-left-radius: .4em;
        border-bottom-left-radius: .4em;
        border-bottom-right-radius: .4em;
        padding: 5px 10px 10px;

        span.msg-name {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: green;
            margin-right: 7px;
            margin-left: 7px;
        }

        span.msg-date {
        font-size: 10px;
        }
    }

    .right-bubble:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 27px solid transparent;
        border-left-color: #dcf8c6;
        border-right: 0;
        border-top: 0;
        margin-top: -13.5px;
        margin-right: -27px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-message" text-right *ngIf="message['sender'] === logged.username">
        <div class="right-bubble">
          <div class="msg-details">
            <span class="msg-name">{{ 'CHAT.ME' | translate}}</span>
            <span class="msg-date">{{message['timestamp'] | date:'short'}}</span>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="message['message'] !== '<message deleted>'" slot="start" name="menu" class="menuIcon"
              (click)="presentActionSheet(message)">
            </ion-icon>
          </div>

          <p text-wrap class="meMessages">{{message['message']}}</p>

          <div>
            <span class="msg-date" *ngIf="message['edited'] !==     null">{{ 'CHAT.EDITED' | translate}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="message['edited'] !== null" class="msg-date">{{message['edited'] | date:'short'}}</span>
          </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a picture to. If you're English isn't the best, this always helps

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the picture correctly, ask me for clarifications if you need as i couldn't explain myself in the best way. PD: Focus on green chat boobles, the css in the blues is not updated yet

Comment: @Ray Do you have a website URL for us to try?

Comment: @ds_secret No, I'm working on development enviroment

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, the key was (width: max-content;) in paragraph tag, the result is the following:

```
.meMessages {
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: max-content;
}
```